# How do you test lists in UnitTest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-unittest, assert

Below is the UnitTest code to find the last occurrence of an element in a list or string. How do I test the below code using UnitTest?

```
class LastOccurenceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_last(self) -> None:

    """ Test case to find index of last occurence of the item in string or list"""

        self.assertEqual(find_last('p','apple','s'),2)
        self.assertEqual(find_last('q','apple','s'),-1) # Target not found
        self.assertEqual(find_last([22],[22,22,33,22],'l'),3)
```

The first two statements work fine but the third one throws the below error as it is not able to count the last occurence :

```
 AssertionError: -1 != 3
```

Below is the function to find this last occurrence:

```
def find_last(target: Any, seq: Sequence[Any],a) -> Optional[int]:

''' return the offset from 0 of the last occurrence of target in seq '''

    try:
        if a=='s':
    
            b: str=""
            c: int= b.join(seq).rindex(target)
            return c

        elif a=='l':

            seq.reverse()
            index = seq.index(target)
            return(len(seq) - index - 1)

    except:
        return -1
```

How do we test lists in UnitTest?

Comment: Target should be a number, not a list, right now it's looking for the list of 22 instead of the element 22 which is why it does not find anything

Comment: Got it, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.index(x[, start[, end]])`, `x` should be the element of the list. So the `[22]` should be `22`.

E.g.

`find_last.py`:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional, Sequence


def find_last(target: Any, seq: Sequence[Any], a) -> Optional[int]:
    ''' return the offset from 0 of the last occurrence of target in seq '''
    try:
        if a == 's':

            b: str = ""
            c: int = b.join(seq).rindex(target)
            return c

        elif a == 'l':

            seq.reverse()
            index = seq.index(target)
            return(len(seq) - index - 1)

    except:
        return -1
```

`test_find_last.py`:

```py
import unittest
from find_last import find_last


class LastOccurenceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_last(self) -> None:
        """ Test case to find index of last occurence of the item in string or list"""

        self.assertEqual(find_last('p', 'apple', 's'), 2)
        self.assertEqual(find_last('q', 'apple', 's'), -1)
        self.assertEqual(find_last(22, [22, 22, 33, 22], 'l'), 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```